# How to fill javascript array from ajax data result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have scripts like this.

**javascript**

```
$.ajax({
   url : "load_data_person.php", 
   dataType:"json",
   success:data_person(arrData)
});

function data_person(info_person){          
   var attr = [];
   var len = [];
   for(j=0;j<info_person.length;j++){
       attr.push(info_person[j][0]);    
       len.push(info_person[j][1]); 
   }
   return [attr, len];
}
```

How can I insert data to variable `info_person` like this:

```
info_person = [['fname',20],['lname',15],['addr',50]];
```

so I can get each value of `attr` and `len`?

Here is the script for `data_person.php`

```
<?php
$qStrPerson = mysql_query("SELECT atribut, len FROM tb_person ORDER BY fname ASC");
$arrFullPerson = array();
while($rStrPerson = mysql_fetch_array($qStrPerson)){
    $arrFullPerson[] = array($rStrPerson[atribut],$rStrPerson[len]);
}

echo json_encode($arrFullPerson);
// it will return like this : Array 0 : ['fname', 20], Array 1 : ['lname',15], Array 2 : ['addr',50]];
?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Post your json data. The one that you were getting

Comment: The info_person will contain data about more than one person data right.? 
Can you more clear on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple jquery to convert the `JSON` to `Javascript array`

```
var array = JSON.parse(your json string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just format the array as you wanted in the server side and then echo it. While receiving the ajax response, you can simply

```
var info_person = json.parse(arData);
```

to convert the json-encoded value into javascript array.